# Copying Matlab plot to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, resize, matlab-figure

I using the clipboard to copy and paste my Matlab plot to excel through the actxserver. However, the dimensions of my figure are not copying over to excel. How do I change to dimensions of the figure? Here is my code...

```
fig = figure('Position',[100 100 200 300]);

print(fig,'-dmeta')

Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');  
ExcelWorkbook=invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open','C:\...');
Sheets = Excel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets.Item(1);
Sheets.Range('A1').PasteSpecial;
ExcelWorkbook.Save;
Excel.Quit;
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Excel is a spreadsheet, not a presentation app.  Don't put pictures in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

The figure property used for printing (or for copying to the clipboard with the `print` function) is not `'Position'`, but `'Paperposition'`.

From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html),

> `Position` — Location and size of figure's drawable area, specified as a  vector of the form `[left bottom width height]`. The drawable area is the inner area of the window, excluding the title bar, menu bar, and tool bars.
>
> `OuterPosition` — Location and size of figure's outer bounds,
>   specified as the vector `[left bottom width height]`.
>
> `PaperPosition` — Figure size and location on page when printing or saving, specified as a four-element vector of the form `[left bottom width height]`

So, add by something like

```
set(fig, 'Paperposition', [1 5 6 12]) %// adjust values as needed
```

before calling `print(fig, '-dmeta')`.